# How many pages of IRA (ASCII 7 bit) text with an average of 65 characters a line and 55 lines a page corresponds to one three-minute telephone call?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Explanation would be much appreciated. So far would I do know is that there are 180 seconds in 3 minutes. This question is part of my data communications class and I am seriously stuck.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I have the feeling you are missing input here: you can find the total number of characters on a page, but a relation to time is missing. Are you sure this is all there is?